# Manipulate not showing the four curves I want to manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, scoping

I've tried to display four functions in a single plot without success and I don't know how I should change my code in order to see the function. Indeed when I run the command I just see the axises but not a single function... Thanks in advance for any tip that might help me with my problem, I link the do-file to the post for you to be able to see my attenpt to do this.

```
0 < θA 
0 < θB
0 < θC 
θA > θB
 θB > θC
0 < β < 1
0 < cA
0 < cB
0 < cC
0 < Fb
0 < Fc
0 < q1A
0 < q2A
0 < q1B
0 < q2B
0 < q2C
0 < τ
0 < b < 1
0 < p
p < 1
0 < a
c > 0

πAC = 
  (((1 + β (1 - p)) (a - τ*θA)^2)/(4 (b + c)) + 
  (β p (a - τ*θC)^2)/(4 (b + c))) - β p*Fc
dAC = d*((1 + β (1 - p)) eA)^2 + d*(β p*eC)^2
dAC = 
  d*(θA*((1 + β (1 - p)) (a - τ*θA))/(4 (b + c)))^2 + 
  ((β p (a - τ*θC))/(4 (b + c)))^2
csAC = 
  ((1 + β (1 - p)) (a (b + 2 c) + bτ*θA) (a - τ*θA))/(8 (b + c)^2) + (β p (a (b + 2 c) + bτ*θC) (a - τ*θC))/(8 (b + c)^2)
wAC = πAC + dAC + csAC

πAA = (1 + β) ((a - τ*θA)^2/(4 (b + c)))
dAA = d*(eA)^2 + d*(eA)^2
dAA = d*2 (θA*(a - τ*θA)/(4 (b + c)))^2
csAA = ((1 + β) (a (b + 2 c) + bτ*θA) (a - τ*θA))/(8 (b + c)^2)
wAA = πAA + dAA + csAA

πBB = (1 + β) ((a - τ*θB)^2/(4 (b + c))) - Fb
dBB = d*(eB)^2 + d*(eB)^2
dBB = d*2 (θB*(a - τ*θB)/(4 (b + c)))^2
csBB = ((1 + β) (a (b + 2 c) + bτ*θB) (a - τ*θB))/(8 (b + c)^2)
wBB = πBB + dBB + csBB

πBC = 
  (((1 + β (1 - p)) (a - τ*θB)^2)/(4 (b + c)) + 
  (β p (a - τ*θC)^2)/(4 (b + c))) - β p*Fc - Fb
dBC = d*((1 + β (1 - p)) eB)^2 + d*(β p*eC)^2
dBC = 
  d*(θB*((1 + β (1 - p)) (a - τ*θB))/(4 (b + c)))^2 + 
  (θC (β p (a - τ*θC))/(4 (b + c)))^2
csBC = 
  ((1 + β (1 - p)) (a (b + 2 c) + bτ*θB) (a - τ*θB))/(8 (b + c)^2) + 
  (β p (a (b + 2 c) + bτ*θC) (a - τ*θC))/(8 (b + c)^2)
wBC = πBC + dBC + csBC

Manipulate[
  Plot[{wAA, wAC, wBB, wBC}, {τ, 0, (2 a)/(θB + θC)}], 
  {a, 2, 3}, 
  {θA, 0, 1}, 
  {θB, 0, 1}, 
  {θC, 0.1, 1}, 
  {c, 0.1, 1}, 
  {b, 0.1, 1}, 
  {p, 0, 1}, 
  {β, 0, 1}, 
  {d, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Your initial inequalities do nothing. If you intend for them to be global assumptions you need to add them to `$Assumptions`. The control variable names inside the `Manipulate` are local and do **not** correspond to the names in the global context. You should define the functions `{wAA, wAC, wBB, wBC}` with explicit parameters and then when used inside the `Manipulate` the function arguments will pass the control variable values to the functions. Use `Evaluate` in the `Plot`, i.e., `Plot[Evaluate@{wAA[...], wAC[...], wBB[...], wBC[...]}, ...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sins are many. Here are the ones I found. There may be others, but by correcting (in some cases rather arbitrarily) the ones I noticed, I was able to get a working `Manipulate`.

1. Writing `bτ` where you should write `b*τ`.
2. Writing duplicate definitions for `dAC`, `dAA`,`dBB`,`dBC`.
3. Not scoping your control variables correctly.
4. Not wrapping your `Plot` expression with `Dynamic`.
5. Not defining the variables `Fb` and `Fc`.

Here is a rewrite of your code that "fixes" the above mentioned problems, perhaps not your satisfaction. However, it does give a working `Manipulate` that you can use as a basis for moving forward with code.

```
With[{Fc = 1, Fb = 7, Fa = 10},
  DynamicModule[
    {πAC, dAC, csAC, wAC, πAA, dAA, csAA, wAA, πBB, dBB, csBB, wBB, πBC, dBC, csBC, wBC},
   Manipulate[
     πAC = 
       (((1 + β (1 - p)) (a - τ*θA)^2)/(4 (b +c)) + (β p (a - τ*θC)^2)/(4 (b + c))) - β* p*Fc;
     dAC = d*(θA*((1 + β (1 - p)) (a - τ*θA))/(4 (b + c)))^2 + ((β*p (a - τ*θC))/(4 (b + c)))^2;
     csAC =
       ((1 + β (1 - p)) (a (b + 2 c) + b*τ*θA) (a - τ*θA))/(8 (b + c)^2) + (β*p (a (b + 2 c) + b*τ*θC) (a - τ*θC))/(8(b + c)^2);
     πAA = (1 + β) ((a - τ*θA)^2/(4(b + c))) - Fa;
     dAA = d*2 (θA*(a - τ*θA)/(4(b + c)))^2;
     csAA = ((1 + β) (a (b + 2 c) + b*τ*θA) (a - τ*θA))/(8 (b + c)^2);
     πBB = (1 + β) ((a - τ*θB)^2/(4 (b + c))) - Fb/2;
     dBB = d*2 (θB*(a - τ*θB)/(4 (b + c)))^2;
     csBB = ((1 + β) (a (b + 2 c) + b*τ*θB) (a - τ*θB))/(8 (b + c)^2);
     πBC = 
       (((1 + β (1 - p)) (a - τ*θB)^2)/(4(b + c)) + (β*p (a - τ*θC)^2)/(4(b + c))) - β* p*Fc - Fb;
     dBC = 
       d*(θB*((1 + β (1 - p)) (a - τ*θB))/(4 (b + c)))^2 + (θC (β* p (a - τ*θC))/(4(b + c)))^2;
     csBC =
       ((1 + β (1 - p)) (a (b + 2 c) + b*τ*θB) (a - τ*θB))/(8(b + c)^2) + (β p (a (b + 2 c) + b*τ*θC) (a - τ*θC))/(8(b + c)^2);
     wAC = πAC + dAC + csAC;
     wAA = πAA + dAA + csAA;
     wBB = πBB + dBB + csBB;
     wBC = πBC + dBC + csBC;
     Dynamic @
       Plot[{wAA, wAC, wBB, wBC}, {τ, 0, (2 a)/(θB + θC)}, 
         PlotLegends -> {"wAA", "wAC", "wBB", "wBC"}],
     {a, 2, 3},
     {θA, 0, 1},
     {θB, 0, 1},
     {θC, 0.1, 1},
     {c, 0.1, 1},
     {b, 0.1, 1},
     {p, 0, 1},
     {β, 0, 1},
     {d, 0, 1}]]]
```

[image: manip]

Answer (score 2):

Not certain this does what you need, but it may give you a way forward.  Note, one can likely do this more economically, but I wanted to show all the pieces deliberately.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{wAC, wAA, wBB, wBC},
  wAC[a_, b_, c_, β_, p_, θA_, τ_, Fc_, bτ_] := 
   Module[{πAC, dAC, csAC},
    πAC = (((1 + β (1 - 
                p)) (a - τ*θA)^2)/(4 (b + 
             c)) + (β p (a - τ*θC)^2)/(4 (b + 
             c))) - β p*Fc;
    dAC = 
     d*((1 + β (1 - p)) θA)^2 + 
      d*(β p*θC)^2; 
    dAC = d*(θA*((1 + β (1 - 
                  p)) (a - τ*θA))/(4 (b + 
               c)))^2 + ((β p (a - τ*θC))/(4 (b + 
             c)))^2; 
    csAC = ((1 + β (1 - p)) (a (b + 2 c) + 
           bτ*θA) (a - τ*θA))/(8 (b + 
            c)^2) + (β p (a (b + 2 c) + 
           bτ*θC) (a - τ*θC))/(8 (b + c)^2);
    πAC + dAC + csAC];
  
  wAA[a_, b_, c_, β_, p_, θA_, τ_, Fc_, bτ_] :=
    Module[{πAA, dAA, csAA},
    πAA = (1 + β) ((a - τ*θA)^2/(4 (b + c)));
    dAA = d*(θA)^2 + d*(θA)^2;
    dAA = d*2 (θA*(a - τ*θA)/(4 (b + c)))^2;
    csAA = ((1 + β) (a (b + 2 c) + 
          bτ*θA) (a - τ*θA))/(8 (b + c)^2);
    πAA + dAA + csAA];
  
  wBB[a_, b_, c_, β_, p_, θA_, τ_, Fc_, bτ_] :=
    Module[{πBB, dBB, csBB},
    πBB = (1 + β) ((a - τ*θB)^2/(4 (b + c))) - 
      Fb;
    dBB = d*(θB)^2 + d*(θB)^2;
    dBB = d*2 (θB*(a - τ*θB)/(4 (b + c)))^2;
    csBB = ((1 + β) (a (b + 2 c) + 
          bτ*θB) (a - τ*θB))/(8 (b + c)^2);
    πBB + dBB + csBB];
  
  wBC[a_, b_, c_, β_, p_, θA_, τ_, Fc_, bτ_] :=
    Module[{πBC, dBC, csBC},
    πBC = (((1 + β (1 - 
                p)) (a - τ*θB)^2)/(4 (b + 
             c)) + (β p (a - τ*θC)^2)/(4 (b + 
             c))) - β p*Fc - Fb; 
    dBC = d*((1 + β (1 - p)) θB)^2 + 
      d*(β p*θC)^2; 
    dBC = d*(θB*((1 + β (1 - 
                  p)) (a - τ*θB))/(4 (b + 
               c)))^2 + (θC (β p (a - \
τ*θC))/(4 (b + c)))^2; 
    csBC = ((1 + β (1 - p)) (a (b + 2 c) + 
           bτ*θB) (a - τ*θB))/(8 (b + 
            c)^2) + (β p (a (b + 2 c) + 
           bτ*θC) (a - τ*θC))/(8 (b + 
            c)^2); πBC + dBC + csBC];
  
  Plot[{
    wAA[a, b, c, β, p, θA, τ, Fc, bτ],
    wAC[a, b, c, β, p, θA, τ, Fc, bτ],
    wBB[a, b, c, β, p, θA, τ, Fc, bτ],
    wBC[a, b, c, β, p, θA, τ, Fc, 
     bτ]}, {τ, 0, (2 a)/(θB + θC)}]
  ],
 {a, 2, 3},
 {θA, 0, 1},
 {θB, 0, 1},
 {θC, 0.1, 1},
 {c, 0.1, 1},
 {b, 0.1, 1},
 {p, 0, 1},
 {β, 0, 1},
 {d, 0, 1},
 {Fc, 0, 1},
 {Fb, 0, 1},
 {bτ, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Also note that it does not appear that your original code set any values for `Fc`, `Fb`, or `bτ`.  I simply added them to the `Manipulate` in this answer, but you may need/want to assign a different range of values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tip it's true that the tau time b was not intentional and this mess up the graph. I still need to be able to change the value of both Fb and Fc and I've managed to get what I wanted taking back your answers! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: You're welcome.  Do take a look at the answer from @m_goldberg.  It provides lots of insight.  If either of the answers you've received help, vote them up.  If one better  answers your problem, check it as the answer.